# Abstract methods in Java

Tags: java, methods, abstract

I want to write an abstract method but the compiler persistently gives this error:

> abstract methods cannot have a body

I have a method like this:

```
public abstract boolean isChanged() {
    return smt else...
}
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: The compiler is telling you exactly what's wrong. It's being persistent because you're trying to compile invalid code. Out of interest, what do *you* think make a method abstract, if you're providing it with a body?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by declaring the method `abstract`?

Comment: @jon @ ted,i have an abstract class and i want to write an abstract method in that class.

Comment: Fine. Just don't provide a body to the method.

Comment: In java an abstract method can never have a body

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Abstract methods means there is no default implementation for it and an implementing class will provide the details.

Essentially, you would have

```
abstract class AbstractObject {
   public abstract void method();
}

class ImplementingObject extends AbstractObject {
  public void method() {
    doSomething();
  }
}
```

So, it's exactly as the error states: your abstract method can not have a body.

There's a full tutorial on Oracle's site at: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

The reason you would do something like this is if multiple objects can share some behavior, but not all behavior.

A very simple example would be shapes:

You can have a generic graphic object, which knows how to reposition itself, but the implementing classes will actually draw themselves.

(This is taken from the site I linked above)

```
abstract class GraphicObject {
    int x, y;
    ...
    void moveTo(int newX, int newY) {
        ...
    }
    abstract void draw();
    abstract void resize();
}

class Circle extends GraphicObject {
    void draw() {
        ...
    }
    void resize() {
        ...
    }
}
class Rectangle extends GraphicObject {
    void draw() {
        ...
    }
    void resize() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23):

If you use the java keyword `abstract` you cannot provide an implementation.

Sometimes this idea comes from having a background in C++ and mistaking the `virtual` keyword in C++ as being "almost the same" as the `abstract` keyword in Java.

In C++ `virtual` indicates that a method can be overridden and polymorphism will follow, but `abstract` in Java is not the same thing.  In Java `abstract` is more like a `pure virtual` method, or one where the implementation must be provided by a subclass.  Since Java supports polymorphism without the need to declare it, all methods are `virtual` from a C++ point of view.  So if you want to provide a method that might be overridden, just write it as a "normal" method.

Now to protect a method from being overridden, Java uses the keyword `final` in coordination with the method declaration to indicate that subclasses cannot override the method.

Comment: Fro a C++ perspective, it's like having `public: virtual bool isChanged() = 0 { return smt else... }`, which is legal. `abstract` is like the `= 0` bit.

Comment: Good job explaining why he might be confused,

Answer (score 4):

The error message tells the exact reason: "abstract methods cannot have a body".

They can only be defined in abstract classes and interfaces (interface methods are implicitly abstract!) and the idea is, that the subclass implements the method.

Example:

```
 public abstract class AbstractGreeter {
   public abstract String getHelloMessage();

   public void sayHello() {
     System.out.println(getHelloMessage());
   }
 }
```

---

```
 public class FrenchGreeter extends AbstractGreeter{

   // we must implement the abstract method
   @Override
   public String getHelloMessage() {
     return "bonjour";
   }
 }
```